# Symfony2 Asset Resource Path

Tags: symfony, assets

In my apache2 settings for /etc/apache2/sites-available/default,
I make my website configuration like this :

```
Alias /new/  "/var/www/symfony/web/"
Alias /new"/var/www/symfony/web/"
<Directory "/var/www/symfony/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
</Directory>
```

And I already enable apache2 rewrite module.

When I access www.example.com/new/app.php,
the resources load fine (css, javascript and image).
The generated source code almost looks like this:

```
<link href="/new/css/main.css" ..... />
.....
```

But when I access www.example.com/new,
the resources DON'T LOAD AT ALL.
When I view the source code, it almost looks like this:

```
<link href="/css/main.css" ..... />
.....
```

Firebug said:

```
www.example.com/css/main.css - 404 Not Found
www.example.com/images/logo.jpg - 404 Not Found
.....
```

What should I do?

Comment: Why are you doing it like this? Why not use the standard vhost configuration?

Comment: give me a link?
I use this because this is the configuration which has been used before I ever lay a hand to the config.

Comment: we use www.example.com/new instead of www.example.com/ because we already have a website running with www.example.com, and it is not symfony2-based. So we decided to try symfony2 and publish it to www.example.com/new.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `.htaccess` file in your `/web` directory with the following code :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
    RewriteRule ^app_dev.php - [L]
    RewriteRule ^app.php - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    # Change below before deploying to production
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

If it still doesn't work you might use standard Vhost configuration, take a look to [VirtualHost Examples](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/vhosts/examples.html) on Apache Website.

For assetic issues go to see the [Asset management documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html) about that.

I hope this help.